# Python for imputing missing values with mean, help me I try this code but error

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df.loc[(data['Perkotaan'].isnull()==True),'Perkotaan']=df['Perkotaan'].mean()
df.loc[(data['Perdesaan'].isnull()==True),'Perdesaan']=df['Perdesaan'].mean()
```

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Perkotaan'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
2901
2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Perkotaan'

Answer (score 0):

your dataframe assigned to df or data?

df.loc[(**data**['Perkotaan'].isnull()==True),'Perkotaan']=df['Perkotaan'].mean()

I think you must change it to df or double-check your selected column.
'Perkotaan' is not a column of your dataframe.

Comment: More specifically, "Perkotaan" is not a column within one of the two DataFrames mentioned.  It probably is within the `df` DataFrame, given the question.  The above code would work if it combining the data from one DataFrame, calculating the "not null" values within the column, and then filtering for these rows specifically.  However, the question isn't clear enough to know if this is what is trying to be calculated.